# what version to use? @angular/service-worker fails to build

Tags: angular

Am I using the correct version of @angular/service-worker? It seems odd to be on a version lower than 2? I've tried (latest)5.0.4 and 5.0.2

My app runs locally using "ng Serve"

Although I've had to use typescript 2.6.2 . Even though I get the message to use >2.4.2 < 2.5.0

My error is as follows:

> The installed version of @angular/service-worker is 5.0.2. This
>   version of the CLI requires the @angular/service-worker version to
>   satisfy >= 1.0.0-beta.5 < 2.0.0. Please upgrade your service worker
>   version.

Here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/router": "5.0.3",
  "@angular/service-worker": "5.0.2",
  "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
  "breeze-bridge-angular": "4.0.1",
  "breeze-client": "1.6.3",
  "core-js": "2.4.1",
  "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
  "jquery": "3.1.1",
  "ngx-bootstrap": "1.9.3",
  "ngx-color-picker": "4.5.0",
  "ngx-gallery": "2.3.0",
  "primeng": "4.3.0",
  "quill": "1.3.2",
  "rxjs": "5.4.2",
  "screenfull": "3.0.2",
  "toastr": "2.1.2",
  "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
  "typescript": "2.6.2",
  "webpack": "^3.9.1",
  "zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.5.5",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
  "@types/node": "8.0.7",
  "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
  "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
  "karma": "1.4.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
  "protractor": "5.1.0",
  "rxjs": "5.1.0",
  "ts-node": "2.0.0",
  "tslint": "4.4.2",
  "typescript": "2.6.2",
  "zone.js": "0.8.12"
}
```

Comment: update your `angular/cli` to [**1.6.0-rc.0**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.6.0-rc.0)

Comment: WOW... what a spot..Well this has definitely progressed me past my original error... 

Who would have thought that using @angular/service-worker@latest wouldnt ever work...

Hats off to ADyson

I have since also found to use:  "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.9",

As code in the node_modules files was failing....